# Using Python quick insert many columns into Sqlite\Mysql

Tags: python, mysql, sqlite, python-db-api

If Newdata is list of x columns, How would get the number unique columns--number of members of first tuple. (Len is not important.)   Change the number of "?" to match columns and insert using the statement below.

```
csr = con.cursor()
csr.execute('Truncate table test.data')
csr.executemany('INSERT INTO test.data VALUES (?,?,?,?)', Newdata)
con.commit()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By "Newdata is list of x columns", I imagine you mean `x` **tuples**, since then you continue to speak of "the first tuple".  If `Newdata` is a list of tuples, `y = len(Newdata[0])` is the number of items in the first one of those tuples.

Assuming that's the number you want (and all tuples had better have the same number of items, otherwise `executemany` *will* fail!), the general idea in @Nathan's answer is right: build the string with the appropriate number of comma-separated question marks:

```
holders = ','.join('?' * y)
```

then insert it in the rest of the SQL statement.  @Nathan's way to insert is right for most Python 2.any versions, but if you have 2.6 or better,

```
sql = 'INSERT INTO testdata VALUES({0})'.format(holders)
```

is currently preferred (it also works in Python 3.any).

Finally,

```
csr.executemany(sql, Newdata)
```

will do what you desire.  Remember to commit the transaction once you're done!-)

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for the maximum number of items in all elements in `Newdata`, it's simply:

```
num_columns = max(len(t) for t in Newdata)
```

This, of course, assumes python 2.5 or greater.

Not that I'm sure what you're attempting would work, but the insert statement would then become:

sql = "INSERT INTO test.data VALUES (%s)" % ",".join('?' * num_columns)